How to make bigger sized presented view same as like earlier version in iOS 18 - Swift
I'm facing an issue in presenting UIViewController in iOS 18.
For the earlier version presentation looks good.
I need a same height and width in every version.
Any quick solution is appreciated. Thank you!
SAMPLE CODE OVER GITHUB
@IBAction func didTap(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if let sVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC") as? SecondVC {
        self.present(sVC, animated: true)
    }
}



Who mark for Close? For what? All details are here...

Can you make a new sample project and check quickly if same behavior comes there too... Plain project with empty view controllers...

@FahimParkar Sample code added above.

@FahimParkar it's done, thanks

The problem is that you have the Presentation Style set to Automatic in the storyboard. Set it to Page Sheet instead.

